# How to detect the transition from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android, instruments

Im using instrumentation to control an application. I was wondering how can I detect if a transition from activity to another is happening. Is there some type of listener ?

Comment: ActivityManager? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the lifecycle functions can help you here

Activity A will have `onPause()` called, and Activity B will have `onCreate()` `onResume()` and `onStart` called

you can place code in these methods to tell you stuff